# Sequelize findAll users with Id but return users from different column

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I have a `followers` join table in my DB.

[image]

`followedByUserId` is the user that is the follower, `followingUserId` is the user they follow.

I am trying to write a `sequelize` query that finds all the entries in the `followingUserId` that are equal to an ID but returns the users that are sitting in the `followedByUserId` column. Can I achieve this?

**QUERY**

```
    getAllUserFollowing: (_, args) => {
      return DB.models.user.findAll({ // if args.id === 1, return user => 2
        include: [{
          model: DB.models.follower,
          where: {
            followingUserId: args.id, 
          },
          order: [
            ['createdAt', 'DESC'],
          ],
        }]
      })
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit `Follower` records by a certain `followingUserId` value that means you want to get all followers of a certain user.
That means you just need to query all `Follower` records where `followingUserId` equals to a given user id and include followed users.
Assuming you have these associations:

```js
Follower.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'followingUserId', as: 'FollowingUser' });
Follower.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'followedByUserId', as: 'FollowedByUser' });
```

you need a query like this:

```js
getAllUserFollowing: async (_, args) => {
      return (await DB.models.Follower.findAll({ // if args.id === 1, return user => 2
        where: {
          followingUserId: args.id, 
        },
        include: [{
          model: DB.models.user,
          as: 'FollowedByUser',
        }],
        order: [
          ['FollowedByUser', 'createdAt', 'DESC'],
        ],
      })).map(x => x.FollowedByUser)
    },
```